# How to handle a messenger pop up which does not always appear?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Some times a messenger pop up comes up on application which is completely random. It may appear in any page and also not as soon as you land on a page. It may take a while to pop up. It is basically company updates or any new feature release related. Is there a way to handle it using Capabilities class or how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not random.
As you said: "It is basically company updates or any new feature release related"

[Feature flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707383/what-is-a-feature-flag) solve your problem, by allowing you to select parts of the of the application to be included or not in a build, through configuration files, e.g.

Thus, you only need to configure these updates to be display only on the environments they make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Id use an If statement on any page it can appear:

```
If(pop is visible)
{
close popup();
}

else{
}
```

Comment: This impacts performance and opens space to conditional hell https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/so-youre-in-if-else-hell-here-s-how-to-get-out-of-it-fc6407fec0e/

Answer (score -1):

I would find the locator of button on the popup. Then, You can surround the button click() in a try-catch block:

```
try{
        btn.click();
 } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("No Button Found");
 }
```